# cant find the publish(or export) button on FlashDevelop app (as3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

i recently switched from cs5.5 to FlashDevelop 
and i have trouble publishing my app (as3)
how do i publish my app to an swf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the compile configuration to Release (In the combobox right near the compile button) and compile. The contents of your bin folder is your "export".